# Allowing periods in datepicker UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

There's a slight problem with the datepicker from the jquery ui: Periods can't be entered into it as it doesn't allow periods. This only happens on fields with a datepicker, and nothing else, and I can't figure out how to allow someone to input periods as a divider for a date.

Jquery version is 1.10.4.

Comment: What `dateFormat` are you using? Please show your code.

Comment: setting proper format it should work fine

Comment: Oh, I have dateformat as "dd-mm-yy". Is there a way to allow multiple formats, by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

You can set `constrainInput` to `false`.

Comment: Well, I've set the dateFormat to "dd-mm-yy" which is probably why it won't work.

There's probably some logic that could be applied to check to see if a period was ever inputted and allow that dateformat, otherwise keep it as is, no?

Actually, I tried disabling that. It didn't do anything. Periods still aren't usable as a form of input. Something like 12.12.14

Well, setting a date format properly certainly works. It probably wouldn't hurt to let users have a checkbox to toggle from dd.mm.yy to dd/mm/yy

Comment: I don't think `constrainInput` was as bad as I thought. Try adding it

Comment: Yeah, that'd probably work, and constrainInput just means adding a bit of validation to date fields to be sure they're actually the right format.